# ghostscript cmyk export yields wrong black

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, icc, cmyk

I'm trying to convert an RGB-pdf file created by Inkscape to a print ready cmyk-pdf using PSOcoated_v3.icc color profile. PDF generation works fine. However, I'd like to check for correct final colors, especially for the black. As I did not found any (free) tool to pick the cmyk color from the final pdf I thought as a first check I convert the RGB-pdf to cmyk-tiff and check the black value. Doing so using

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE \
-sDEVICE=tiff32nc \
-sDefaultRGBProfile=sRGB2014.icc \
-dOverrideICC \
-sOutputICCProfile=PSOcoated_v3.icc \
-sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK \
-sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK \
-sOutputFile=rgb.pdf \
 cmyk.tiff
```

yields a cmyk black value of [0.83, 0.67, 0.51, 0.95]. Contrarily, when I use libcms2 to convert rgb (0,0,0) to cmyk I get [0.92, 0.64, 0.45, 0.96] which matches (almost) some information about the PSOcoated_v3.icc profile I found [here](http://blog.guidosonnenberg.de/how-black-is-black). To confirmed that the source RGB-file black reads (0,0,0) I convert the RGB-pdf to an RGB-tiff and do find the black to be (0,0,0).

Am I missing something in the command of might this be a gs bug?

Comment: You don't need -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK because the tiff32nc device only supports DeviceCMYK so its sets it for you. You also don't need -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK, that switch **only** has any effect with the pdfwrite family of devices. In this case it will have no effect. I've asked the relevant person to look at this post regarding the colour value. You don't say which version of Ghostscript you are using though

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The unnecessary options are from the original pdf to pdf convert task. I'm using the binary from the gs homepage for unix, gs-922-linux-x86_64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I take an RGB color of [0,0,0] in sRGB color space and convert it to the CMYK value defined by the PSO coated v3 ICC profile in Photoshop (using Adobe ACE CMM in Photoshop), I get exactly the CMYK values you are seeing with gs, that is [0.83, 0.67, 0.51, 0.95].

That was using a relative colorimetric rendering intent with black point compensation enabled.   Those are the settings that gs would be using for lcms by default.

I suspect that when you use libcms2, it is using a different rendering intent.  For example, when I use the perceptual rendering intent with Adobe ACE I get [0.90, 0.64, 0.45, 0.96].

Note that you can specify with gs what rendering intent you want to use with 
-dRenderIntent=0/1/2/3 .  See https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#ICC_color_parameters for details.

Comment: Great hint! I was not aware that the rendering intent has such an influence. When setting the intent to RELATIVE_COLORIMETRIC in lcms the same values are reproduced. Thanks for helping me out on that.